# Wi-Fi stops working when I attach wireless mouse to my laptop

Tags: wireless-networking, router, mouse

I am using an **[HP 15-r249TU](http://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c04576740)**, and today I bought a wireless **Redragon 2400DPI** mouse. When I attach the mouse adapter to my laptop, my Internet connection stops working instantly. I have a TP-Link router and I am using Wi-Fi.

Comment: Have you tried putting it in a different port?

Comment: Yes, not only different port but in different laptop also. It have same issue with Lenovo laptop @Cand3r

Answer (score 56):

That's probably a 2.4 GHz wireless mouse and you're probably using 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi, so your mouse is probably interfering with your Wi-Fi signals.

Try changing your TP-Link router's channel and the mouse system's channel so they don't overlap. Consider switching to 5 GHz Wi-Fi or a wired USB mouse.

Comment: In my dropdown of TP-LInk panel there is 1 to 11, i tried all and still have same problem. http://prntscr.com/byprqs

Comment: @VipulHadiya Did you double-check that the change got applied each time (like by checking what channel your laptop said it was on)? Also, if your TP-Link supports 40MHz-wide channel operation in 2.4GHz, disable that (set it to 20MHz-wide channels only). You really only need to test channels 1, 6, and 11. What are your frequency/channel choices for your mouse?

Comment: Is it common for mice to interfere? To have the same frequency as WiFi? I've used many wireless mice and many different routers (most using 2.4 GHz) and I've never seen the problem that OP describes. I'm curious as to what's different.

Comment: @Kat I also used to use Amkette wireless mouse. There was no problem but it happens with this new one.

Comment: @Spiff How can i check GHz? I can see only numbers. Can you guide me?

Comment: @VipulHadiya If your router doesn't have a "5GHz" option, all of the channels are likely 2.4 GHz

Comment: I can second the answer, I had the same interference problem with a wireless headset. However, I did not find a way to solve my problem at that time, so I'll be happily coming back to this looking for solutions later!

Comment: Whose bright idea was it to sell 2.4GHz wireless mice? lol

Comment: Really my mouse is working as a break for internet connection. Suppose i am watching a video on youTube, and if i plug adapter in. Video show me buffering symbol. and facebook messenger started to 'reconnectiing...''

Comment: What can be solution if i can't change bandwidth of my router?

Answer (score 11):

I agree with Spiff's answer - but there may be a solution

Have you tried waiting and letting the mouse and receiver (adapter) bind? It's likely that when you power the receiver on the laptop side, it goes into a bind mode and screams out for all to hear, until it finds a mouse. If it manages to find a mouse, interference may calm down enough for you to reconnect to your router, however speeds will still be impacted.

Answer (score 2):

Some wireless HID devices (as Logitech) frequently come with an extended cord ~2 m long, with filters for only FS operation for USB (USB RF dongles are usually FS-devices). When placing the HID transceiver apart from laptop, it will separate Wi-Fi and mouse antennas, and your setup might start working.

Also please be aware that 2.4 GHz HID devices might interfere with USB 3.0 operations as well, there is even a formal USB-IF certification test for this.

Comment: FS stands for what?

Comment: FS stands for "full-speed" mode of USB, 12 Mb/s signaling rate. There is also "LS", low-speed (1.5Mb/s). And there is HS (high-speed, 480Mb/s), all on the same pair of wires (D+ and D-).

Comment: So how does the cable allow devices to only use FS mode?  Seems odd to use a 6-foot cord with a cordless mouse, FWIW.

Comment: You don't believe me, do you? The wireless transceiver is FS, so the cradle is low quality, and HS does not work. The original intent of the extension cradle was to put the transceiver in close proximity when using floor-standing PC box, http://www.ebay.com/itm/Logitech-Wireless-RF-Receiver-P-N-810-000272-for-Mouse-w-Extension-Cradle-/272132681163. There are also shorter dongles http://techreport.com/r.x/logitech-k400/dongle.jpg

Comment: I didn't say I didn’t beleive you.  Though a plain wire with the wrong impedance for HS makes more sence than a device engineered to somehow detect which protocol is being used and block them.